# Adding a counter for various div container

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, counter

first of all I know that this title is kinda confusing but I am going to explain what I want to do.

I created a simple .html and .js file which has different div tags. I looped the div tags with a for loop and the text of the div container should be added to a table that I created.

```
<HTML>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="divContainer">
      <div class="div">
        one
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        two
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        three
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        four
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        five
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        six
      </div>
    </div>


    <table id="table">

    </table>

    <p id="output">

    </p>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

JavaScript file:

```
var divLists = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < divLists.length; i++) {

    var divList = divLists[i];

    divList.onclick = function() {
      x(this.innerHTML);
    }
  }
};

function x(y) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var Row = table.insertRow();
  var Cell = Row.insertCell(0);
  var newText = document.createTextNode(y);
  Cell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

I also put the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avj4zg21/11/

So by clicking on "one", "two", "three",... it will be added to the table but it want to add a counter. So for example if I click on one it should be added to the table and if I click a second or third time on it there should be a counter behind the one like: "one (3 times pressed)".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` to keep track of the clicked items and increment the existing ones:

```js
var divLists = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < divLists.length; i++) {

    var divList = divLists[i];

    divList.onclick = function() {
      x(this.innerHTML);
    }
  }
};

let map = {};

function checkNumber(number){
     if(map[number])
          map[number] = map[number] + 1;
     else
          map[number] = 1;
     return map[number];
}

function x(y) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  let rows = table.rows;
  let count = checkNumber(y);
  var Row = table.insertRow();
  var Cell = Row.insertCell(0);
  Cell.innerHTML = count;
  Cell = Row.insertCell(0);
  Cell.innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="divContainer">
      <div class="div">
        one
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        two
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        three
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        four
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        five
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        six
      </div>
    </div>


    <table id="table">

    </table>
    
    <p id="output">
    
    </p>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generates an incremented id (as a class) for each row.  Adds counter as data attribute using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).  If you need to have multiple divs with the same content increment the same counter, you will have to use a map, attach data, or scan contents.
Note: your current scheme takes the entire HTML contents of the divs which is actually `"           one"` rather than a simple word string.

```js
var divLists = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < divLists.length; i++) {

    var divList = divLists[i];

    let idx = i; // store current index, so it can be used below
    divList.onclick = function() {
      x(this.innerHTML, idx);
    }
  }
};

function x(y, idx) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var Row = table.getElementsByClassName(`id${idx}`)[0] || table.insertRow();
  Row.classList.add(`id${idx}`); // generate `id${idx}` as a class
  var Cell = Row.cells[0] || Row.insertCell(0);
  Cell.innerHTML = y + (Row.dataset.count ? `(${Row.dataset.count})`: '');
  Row.dataset.count = (+Row.dataset.count + 1)||2;
  // convert count to number increment, or if not defined yet start at 2
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="divContainer">
      <div class="div">
        one
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        two
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        three
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        four
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        five
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        six
      </div>
    </div>


    <table id="table">

    </table>
    
    <p id="output">
    
    </p>
  </body>
</HTML>
```